# How do I refresh a webpage widget

Tags: browser, widget, lotus-notes, composite, page-refresh

I have created a webpage widget from an external website in Lotus Notes and added it to a composite application. this works great. but how do I refresh the page to see new content.

there is not options menu choice for refresh and the widget browsers have no right click menu.

Answer (score 0):

it's easy, to update manuel just klick in the widget and then F5 for Browserupdate.